# GraphOfTheGodsFactory and Gremlin query

Tags: graph-databases, gremlin, titan

I'm trying the queries given [here](https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/wiki/Indexing-Backend-Overview#querying-an-index) in java:

```
import static com.tinkerpop.blueprints.Compare

Graph g = GraphOfTheGodsFactory.create("gods")
g.query().has("age", GREATER_THAN, 1000).vertices().iterator().hasNext
```

But this seems to return `false` although that the below one return `true` but doesn't take benefits of the index:

```
new GremlinPipeline(g.getVertices()).has("age", GREATER_THAN, 1000).toList().size() > 0
```

Does [the example 5 here](https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/wiki/Indexing-Backend-Overview#querying-an-index) works for someone ?

Here is a project I created to test: https://github.com/joan38/TestTitan
This should print the names of Gods who has more than 1000 years old, but it doesn't.

I really fell that TinkerPop or Titan is not straight forward :( or maybe it's me.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

That's an ElasticSearch pitfall. The problem is that your code simply runs too fast. The default refresh interval of ES is 1 second. I'm not aware of any method to configure this interval when using embedded ES, so all you can do is: add a `Thread.sleep(1000)` between the code to load the graph and the code to query the data.

Comment: It didn't worked with a `Thread.sleep(2000)`. I also updated the Github project.

Comment: Not sure what you did now, but check out this Gist to see that it worked by simply adding a ```Thread.sleep(1000)``` in the old version: https://gist.github.com/dkuppitz/2302132fa8c46f2c47af

Comment: Oh I see you put the sleep just after querying and before reading the values. But this seems to be a big issue because every time I query I will have to sleep 1s... Also in the updated project where I added more data we can see that the index is not used. (Run `sbt clean "run -i es -q graphQuery` to see)

Comment: You can also call ```Thread.sleep(1000)``` right after ```GraphOfTheGodsFactory.create("target/db")```; the query is not sent to Cassandra/ES as long as you don't iterate over it. However, of course you'll never do a ```Thread.sleep(1000)``` in your real application. You just need to keep in mind that data indexed in ES is not immediately available. This shouldn't be a problem at all for 99% of all applications. If it's a problem for your application, you can still use a separate ES process and define a lower refresh interval in ES' configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it is not returning `true` for you.  See my Titan Console session:

```
gremlin> g = GraphOfTheGodsFactory.create("gods")
==>titangraph[local:gods]
gremlin> g.query().has("age", GREATER_THAN, 1000).vertices().iterator().hasNext()
==>true
```

To go a step further:

```
gremlin> g.query().has("age", GREATER_THAN, 1000).vertices()
==>v[20]
==>v[4]
==>v[16]
==>v[32]
gremlin> g.query().has("age", GREATER_THAN, 1000).vertices()._().age
==>4500
==>10000
==>5000
==>4000
gremlin> g.query().has("age", GREATER_THAN, 1000).has('name','saturn').vertices()._().map
==>{name=saturn, type=titan, age=10000}
gremlin> new GremlinPipeline(g.getVertices()).has("age", GREATER_THAN, 1000).toList().size()
==>4
```

Perhaps try it out in the Titan Console and make sure that works for you as it did for me here.

Comment: In the console it is working well. I recreated a project to test only that. I forgot to precise that I'm in Scala but I should be able to do Java normally. I will try in a new Java project and I come back here.

Comment: See my edit with the repo where I but the test in Java